# Find the volume above the $x-y$ plane, under the surface $r^2=2z$, and inside $r=2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Find the volume above the $x-y$ plane, under the surface $r^2=2z$, and inside $r=2$

I'm taking this calc 3 class online and I'm completely lost this week with double and triple integrals.

I've stared at the above problem for about an hour and I cannot even figure out how to get started here.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

As noted in the comments before, we need to know what $r$ is.

Simple and fitting would be $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, so we operate in cylindrical coordinates.

Fist you should figure out what the three surfaces are:

- x-y plane is all points with $z=0$.
- In this case $r^2 = 2z$ means circles around the $z$-axis with radius
  $r = \sqrt{2z}$.
- $r = 2$ would be a cylinder along the $z$-axis.

Here is a cut through the volume at $y=0$:

[image: cut]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLSnh.png))